# TensorFlow error using AVX instructions on Linux while working on Windows on the same machine

Tags: linux, tensorflow, avx

I'm using a Dual-Boot machine with Windows and Ubuntu and try to run a code which works well while windows is used but errors when Ubuntu is used.
The error says:

```
F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

While running the same code using Windows it gives a similar warning but still runs.

Couldn't find any solution regarding to the problem on the net.

**System specifications:**

- Ubuntu 18.10
- Python 2.7.15+
- TensorFlow 1.12.0

Comment: Are you running Linux inside a VM that doesn't enable AVX for the guest OS?  That would be a problem.  What exact warning does your Windows version give?  Is it that AVX is available but your Windows TensorFlow was *not* compiled to use it?  That's the opposite error.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/cpuinfo` say?