# R Session keeps aborting when using Keras to train a neural network

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a neural network that will be able to do binary classification on a dataset. However, when I try to use the fit function with my model I get a window pop up saying "R Session Aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated."

What could be causing it to crash?

The data set is 5 columns by 28200 rows. With one column being the target variable.

I have set tensorflow to version 1.4 as the newer versions apparently cause older computers such as mine to crash, but that has not fixed the problem.

As well as I used to get it crashing when I specified the layers but then I changed them and it no longer crashed until I tried to fit the model.

```
x_train <- as.matrix(training_set[,2:5])
y_train <- as.matrix(training_set[,1])
x_test <- as.matrix(test_set[,2:5])
y_test <- as.matrix(test_set[,1])


model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(4)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')


 model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = 32,
  epochs = 10,
  validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
)
```

Comment: Generally it is the backend that causes the crash, ie. Tensorflow, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723217/is-there-a-version-of-tensorflow-not-compiled-for-avx-instructions/55165620#55165620) for an approach to building that shouldn't crash.